# Raspberry Pi: how to send serial command using Ethernet?

Tags: python, cherrypy, raspberry-pi

I have a python script, which will start cherrypy webserver when run in the terminal. In the script, i use pyserial by importing `serial`, then i open up the port /dev/ttyAMA0 and i can send any serial commands.

```
 @cherrypy.expose
 def login (self, **data):
    passcode = data.get("passcode", None)
    print "logging in using passcode %s"%passcode ,type(passcode)

    import serial
    import time
    #open connection
    serialport=serial.Serial ("/dev/ttyAMA0", 9600, timeout=0.5)
    #write in user sign in code
    serialport.write("\x03LI%s\x0D"%passcode)
    #get reply 
    reply=serialport.readlines(1)
    print reply, type(reply)
```

However, since there is an Ethernet port and i can send the serial command to that similar device using Netcat, how can i let this script to send commands through the ethernet port instead of the serial port? What should i change?

sorry but i'm really clueless on how to do this. i've searched through google and i can't find answers. :(

Comment: `socat` is your friend ;)

Comment: thanks! it's almost the same as netcat. but how to use either one of them? :s

Comment: It's not *the same* as `netcat`, although they are related. You could probably connect to a local TCP socket in python, but redirect the byte stream to a serial device using socat. python would not even recognize this. But of course there will be *true* python solutions as well. Note that I'm not a python expert, but once we did it at work *the socat way* :) That's why I left the comment.

Comment: BTW: There is a dedicated raspberry py stack exchange: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 2):

What about using the [`socat`](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat.html) command? Using the following command line you can make `/dev/ttyAMA0` accessible via `eth 127.0.0.1:5555`:

```
socat PTY,link=/dev/ttyAMA0 TCP:127.0.0.1:5555
```

Comment: :D really????? i'm so delighted! thank you! i'm going to try it right away and let you know again :)

Comment: yep! `scoat` rocks!!! :) Note that I'll be AFK a while. But will return to here later..

Comment: oh yeah! :D okay noted! thanks again!! but can i ask why is it 5555? as in is it a fix number? :O

Comment: no, just a port.. you can use another one of your choice. also you can use the *outer* ip, like `192.168.0.10` if want to access the bytestream over network.

Comment: umm i get permission denied. is there somewhere else that i need to configure?

Comment: sorry have no much time, need to hurry. will make some tests later.. try to google until I'm back.. maybe there is a little problem with the syntax.. But I'm sure socat can do that

Comment: Umm, here's another question when you're back: currently i'm connecting to the device with 3 wires (Gnd, TXD, RXD) from raspberry Pi. so if i remove them, and connect an ethernet cable from that device to the modem (which R-Pi also connected to), do i need to configure something else at somewhere? (i don't really get the logic on how the data will flow >< )

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29920/discussion-between-hek2mgl-and-yvonnezoe)

Answer (score 1):

A Python based approach to the problem is to use the pyserial's built-in [network ports](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/pyserial_api.html#rfc-2217-network-ports) functionality (which is based on the [RFC2217](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2217.html) standard).

In your server (where the serial device is attached) you run a network serial server - you can use the [serial port bridge](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples.html#single-port-tcp-ip-serial-bridge-rfc-2217) example e.g:

```
% python /usr/share/doc/python-serial/examples/rfc2217_server.py -p 7000 /dev/ttyAMA0
```

And in your client python code you attach to it using a rfc2217 style url with the newer `serial_for_url` (as mentioned in the [howto](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/appendix.html#how-to)) e.g:

```
serial.serial_for_url('rfc2217://yourservername:7000')
```

Note: Newer versions of pyserial now supports a number of other network transport options see the various [URL handlers](https://pyserial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/url_handlers.html).

Comment: the howto link appears to be broken fyi.

Comment: Thanks - just updated the links and added info on URL handlers.